# Page-up doesn't work inside bash inside conqueterm inside vim

Tags: bash, vim, vim-plugin, bash-completion

I've just started using ConqueTerm for Vim this morning. It's pretty cool; however, it's not working as I hoped. I have the following set inside my .bashrc

```
bind '"\e[5~": history-search-backward'
bind '"\e[6~": history-search-forward'
```

This allows me to press PageUp and PageDown while typing commands in bash to automatically search the command history.

However, it doesn't work with ConqueTerm in vim. Tab completion, colours etc. all work, but when I press page up, it literally does a page up

I tried putting the following lines in my vimrc, but that didn't work.

```
imap [5~ <PageUp>
imap [6~ <PageDown>
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I don't think your mapping is correct. To map pageup and pagedown properly type `<C-v>` (Control v) followed by pageup/pagedown. This should generate something that starts with `^[` which is the ascii symbol in vim for escape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Bind` is a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) built-in command. It is nothing to do with vim. PgUp and PgDown is used by vim on the most usual way, and You cannot show [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) command history in vim. Actually You can, but it seems to be pointless to me.

If I know well the best place for key-bindings for [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) is the ~/.inputrc file. I added your lines to it

```
"\e[5~": history-search-backward
"\e[6~": history-search-forward
```

And it works well! But the "standard" way is the up and down arrow for these.

Please describe what is your goal!

ConqueTerm interprets "\e" (escape) before bash does. This is why this would not work.

Comment: So your suggested additions to ~/.inputrc *won't* help ConqueTerm?